# need VBA code to make a folder visible in the navigation/treeview pane of Outlook 2010

Tags: c#, vba, treeview, outlook, directory

To select a folder the following seems to work, and I see the content of the folder

```
Set olApp.ActiveExplorer.currentFolder = tgtFolder    ' As Outlook.MAPIFolder
```

but the treeview (AKA navigation pane on the left side) does not display the currently selected folder.  How do I go about doing that?

Thank you.

C# solution will also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
Dim mapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder = app.GetNamespace("mapi").GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
mapi.Display()
```